# Java/VSCode "file.java is not on the classpath of project, only syntax errors are reported"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm new to java and keep getting this error on and on in vs code. How do I solve this?

Comment: by putting the file on the classpath. You should also adopt naming conventions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by opening your current project folder in vs code, then navigate to "Java Projects" > "properties" > "clean workspace".

Comment: Worked for me. There was a prompt to clean up the language server workspace. Cleanup resolved the warning.

Answer (score 5):

Press "Ctrl + Shift + P", choose "java : Clean java Language Server workspace".
If not run, right click on src, choose "add folder to java source path"

Answer (score 0):

Tried other solutions here but didn't work for me, what eventually worked for me was:

1. Moving the java file to a folder. (A project folder)
2. Make sure the project folder is opened on the explorer tab in VS codes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).